# Real Analysis, Folland Problem 1.3.11 Measures

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Background information - Let $X$ be a set well equipped with a $\sigma$-algebra $M$. A measure on $M$ (or on $(X,M)$ or on $X$ if $M$ is understood) is a function $\mu: M \rightarrow [0,\infty]$ such that

i.) $\mu(\emptyset) = 0$

ii.) if $\{E_j\}_{1}^{\infty}$ is a sequence of disjoint sets in $M$ then $\mu(\cup_{1}^{\infty}E_j) = \sum_{1}^{\infty}\mu(E_j)$

Property (ii.) is called countable additivity and implies finite additivity:

ii.*) if $E_1,\ldots, E_n$ are disjoint sets in $M$ then $\mu(\cup_{1}^{n}E_j) = \sum_{1}^{n}\mu(E_j)$

because one can take $E_j = \emptyset$ for $j >n$. A function $\mu$ that satisfies (i.) and (ii.*) but not (ii.) is called a finitely additive measure.

> A finitely additive measure $\mu$ is a measure if and only if it is continuous from below. If $\mu(X) < \infty$, $\mu$ is a measure if and only if it is continuous from above.

The proof of the first part is provided in the answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1785238/a-finitely-additive-measure-is-a-measure-if-and-only-if-we-have-continuity-from/1785296?noredirect=1#comment3646040_1785296)

Attempted proof of second part - Let $\{E_j\}_{1}^{\infty}$ be a sequence of disjoint sets in $M$ and $\mu(X) < \infty$. Let $$F_k = \bigcap_{1}^{\infty}E_j$$ As you can see $F_1\supset F_2 \supset \ldots$, so the $F_k$'s are a decreasing sequence of sets and clearly $$\bigcap_{1}^{\infty}F_k = \bigcap_{1}^{\infty}E_j$$
Now from continuity from above $$\mu\left(\bigcap_{1}^{\infty}E_j\right) = \mu\left(\bigcap_{1}^{\infty}F_k\right) = \lim_{k\rightarrow \infty}\mu(F_k)$$
Now what I want to do is apply De'Morgans law and conclude that we will have continuity from above being the same as continuity from below but I am not sure if that I can actually do that. Any suggestions is greatly appreciated.

Comment: If the $E_j$'s are disjoint then each $F_k$ is empty.

Comment: Ok so I should not make the $E_j$'s disjoint then?

Comment: That depends on what you are trying to prove.

Comment: Is it not clear what I am trying to prove?

Comment: No, not really. Perhaps you should write out the condition you need to verify for $\mu$ to be a measure.

Comment: To prove $\mu$ is a measure you need to prove that $$\mu \left( \bigcup_{j=1}^\infty E_j \right) = \sum^\infty_{j=1} \mu(E_j)$$ whenever $\{E_j \}$ is a sequence of *disjoint* measurable sets. It is unclear that this is what you are doing above because you seem to be worried about the intersection $\cap^\infty_{j=1} E_j$ when this shouldn't really come into play. You also define $F_k = \cap^\infty_{j=1} E_j$ which has no dependence on $k$.

Comment: As written, the assertion is wrong. A finitely additive measure (defined on a $\sigma$-algebra) is a measure if and only if it is continuous from below. If $\mu(X) < \infty$, then continuity from below is equivalent to continuity from above.

Comment: @DanielFischer are you talking about the assertion of my question or my attempted proof?

Comment: The assertion of the question. Since there are measures with $\mu(X) = \infty$, it can't be true as written. Probably they meant "a finitely additive measure $\mu$ with $\mu(X) < \infty$ is a measure if and only if …".

Comment: And now we're there. Do you know that a measure is continuous from below? Have you already shown that a finitely additive measure that is continuous from below is a measrue?

Comment: Yes, I have it linked to this question

Comment: Okay. Then it remains to see that if $\mu$ is a finitely additive measure with $\mu(X) < \infty$, then $\mu$ is continuous from below if and only if it is continuous from above. You get that by taking complements.

Comment: Ok, I thought that is why we use De'Morgan's law. Is the way I set up my proof correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Let $\mu$ be a finitely additive measure such that $\mu(X) < \infty$. Then $\mu$ is a measure if and only if it is continuous from above.

**Proof**:

($\Rightarrow$) Since $\mu$ is a measure, we know it is continuous from below. Now, let $\{F_j\}_{1}^{\infty}$ be a non-increasing sequence of sets in $M$. Define $E_k=X \setminus F_k$. Then $\{E_k\}_{1}^{\infty}$ is a non-decreasing sequence of sets in $M$, and $\cap_{j=1}^{\infty}F_j=X \setminus \cup_{k=1}^{\infty}E_k$, so we have, using the fact that $\mu(X) < \infty$,
\begin{align}
 \mu(\cap_{j=1}^{\infty}F_j)&= \mu(X \setminus \cup_{k=1}^{\infty}E_k)=\mu(X)-\mu(\cup_{k=1}^{\infty}E_k) =\mu(X) -\lim_{k\to \infty}\mu(E_k)=\\
&=\mu(X) -\lim_{k\to \infty}\mu(X \setminus F_k)=\mu(X) -\lim_{k\to \infty}(\mu(X)-\mu(F_k))= \lim_{k\to \infty}\mu(F_k)
\end{align}
So $\mu$ is continuous from above.

($\Leftarrow$) Let $\{E_j\}_{1}^{\infty}$ is a sequence of disjoint sets in $M$. Define $F_k= \bigcap_{j=1}^k (X \setminus E_j)$. Then $\{F_k\}_{1}^{\infty}$ is a non-increasing sequence of sets in $M$ and $\cap_{k=1}^{\infty}F_k=X \setminus \cup_{j=1}^{\infty}E_j$, so we have, using the fact that $\mu(X) < \infty$,

\begin{align} 
\mu(X) - \mu(\cup_{j=1}^{\infty}E_j)&=\mu(X \setminus \cup_{j=1}^{\infty}E_j) = \mu(\cap_{k=1}^{\infty}F_k)= 
\lim_{k \to \infty} \mu(F_k)= \\
&=\lim_{k \to \infty} \mu( \cap_{j=1}^{k}(X \setminus E_j))=\lim_{k \to \infty} \mu(X \setminus \cup_{j=1}^{k}E_j)= \\
&= \lim_{k \to \infty} (\mu(X)-\mu(\cup_{j=1}^{k}E_j))=\mu(X)-\lim_{k \to \infty} \mu(\cup_{j=1}^{k}E_j)= \\
& =\mu(X)-\lim_{k \to \infty} \sum_{j=1}^{k} \mu(E_j)= \mu(X)-\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \mu(E_j) 
\end{align}
Using againg that $\mu(X) < \infty$, we have 
$$\mu(\cup_{1}^{\infty}E_j) = \sum_{1}^{\infty}\mu(E_j)$$

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

1). $X\setminus \left( \bigcup_{j=1}^\infty E_j \right)=\bigcap_{j=1}^\infty(X\setminus E_j) $

2). $\mu (X\setminus E_j)=\mu (X)-\mu (E_j);\ (\mu$ is finite).

Answer (score 0):

Work with $F_i=E_i^C$ then $\mu(\cap F_i)=\mu(X)-\lim\mu(E_i)$ by cont from above but the left hand side is $\mu( (\cup E_i)^C)$ by de Morgan and so is $\mu(X)-\mu(\cup E_i)$ and you are done.